# Mobius transformation satisfying certain properties

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I'm having some trouble showing that a Mobius transformation $F$ maps $0$ to $\infty$ and $\infty$ to $0$ iff $F(z)=dz^{-1}$ for some $d \in \mathbb{C}.$ Mainly with the "only if" part. Do I need to use pictures?

This is Exercise $23$ in Section $3.3$ of Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. What are $f(0)$ and $f(\infty)$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$? Deduce further.

(It's a bad idea for the exercise to use the letter $d$ in my opinion; just know you're trying to conclude the function is a constant multiple of the reciprocal function $1/z$.)

Comment: It is possibly confusing that you use $d$ in a way other than it appears in OP.

Comment: I have that $f(0)=\infty \implies \frac{b}{d}=\infty$ and $f(\infty)=0 \implies \frac{a}{c}=0.$ Also, $ad-bc \neq 0...$

Comment: @Anonymous So what do $\frac{b}{d}=\infty$ and $\frac{a}{c}=0$ tell you?

Comment: @whacka Since $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C},$ and $\infty \notin \mathbb{C},$ these two equalities tell me that $d=0$ and $a=0$, correct?

Comment: @Anonymous Correct. So now what does $f$ look like?

Comment: @whacka So $f(z) = \frac{\frac{b}{c}}{z},$ where $\frac{b}{c} \in \mathbb{C}!$

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}$